# How to get Amazon products' info without signing up for associates program?

Tags: amazon-product-api

We need to use to products API to track our clients'/brands' products and their sales so that we can show them that they are getting ROI from the deals they do on our platform. We have nothing to do with the associates program. Can we use the products API without signing up for the program? This is because they will cancel our associates membership if we don't drive sales in 180 days. Our purpose is not to drive sales but analytics on amazon products. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Have you asked Amazon?  This reads as either a) a company policy or partnership question, or b) asking how to hack their API.  a) is off-topic.  b) is technically a programming question but you probably don't want to be caught doing it.

Comment: @DaveS - No I am not trying to hack or do anything like that. I meant getting that data without joining the program, officially. That data is public anyway, it's just getting it via an API is the thing I need. I have searched a lot and couldn't find anything. Amazon sometimes acts weird in terms of documentation. So I just wanted to know if someone else knows that something like this exists or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to PAPI, you either need to scrape the data yourself or need to use other third party API.

We use the [amazon-price](https://rapidapi.com/ebappa1971/api/amazon-price) API from RapidAPI, it supports price/rating/review count fetching for up to 1000 products in a single request. We are in the same boat as we need to know the price of amazon products but don't actually have anything to do with advertising amazon products.